# DSum query slow when it is a Make Table query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am trying to capture which products account for 80% of sales and therefore need a way of having a running sum as well as a total sum for my data.  The query runs relatively quick if it is just a Select query, but once I change it to a Make Table query it bogs down.  If examining a year's worth of sales, I get approximately 26,000 distinct product codes.

Here is the SQL code of the query:

```sql
SELECT
    tblRaw.ID,
    tblRaw.PRODUCT,
    tblRaw.PRODUCT_DESC,
    tblRaw.CAT_1,
    tblRaw.CATEGORY_DESC,
    tblRaw.QTY_Sold,
    tblRaw.Sales,
    tblRaw.Cost,
    IIf([Sales]=0,0,([Sales]-[Cost])/[Sales]) AS [GM%],
    Format(DSum("[Sales]","[tblRaw]","[ID]<=" & [ID]),"$#,##0") AS RunTot,
    Format(DSum("[Sales]","[tblRaw]"),"$#,##0") AS TotSum,
    ([RunTot]/[TotSum]) AS CummPer,
    IIf([CummPer]<=0.8,"A",IIf([CummPer]<=0.95,"B","C")) AS Class,
    tblOH_Company.OH_QTY AS QTY_OH,
    tblOH_Company.Value AS Value_OH
FROM tblRaw LEFT JOIN tblOH_Company ON tblRaw.PRODUCT = tblOH_Company.Product
ORDER BY tblRaw.Sales DESC;
```

Note: If I remove the joined table (tblOH_Company), I see no improvement.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. An append query was no faster than make table

Comment: Any specific reason for storing the query data in a separate table?

Comment: I need to be able to do summaries and pull out selected data for reporting and this is likewise too slow if done against the DSum query.